# How to convert string into array of objects in angular typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have following string , how to convert it into array of objects

```
{"Car":
"["
   {"Carid":234,"CompanyCode":null}","
   {"Carid":134,"CompanyCode":"maruti"}","
   {"Carid":145,"CompanyCode":"sedan"}","

"]"
}
```

tried JSON.parse , it is giving error Unexpected token '{ 'at position 11

tried eval , it is giving error Unexpected token ':'

Comment: that string isn't valid JSON.  you have all sorts of weird things going on with the quotes, opening and closing braces, etc.....

Comment: Remove the quotes around the following elements: `[`, `]`, `,`

Comment: basically, **don't** wrap the braces in quotes, and **don't** wrap the separators (`,`) in quotes.

Comment: how to remove the double quotes around curly braces and comma , it is coming from backend , can i use .replace?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to solve this kind of problem

```js
let s = '{"Car":"[" {"Carid":234,"CompanyCode":null}"," {"Carid":134,"CompanyCode":"maruti"}","{"Carid":145,"CompanyCode":"sedan"}",""]"}';


let matchReplace = [['"\\,"',','],['"\\["','['],['\\,"\\]"',']']];
matchReplace.forEach((reg)=>{
  let regularExp = new RegExp(reg[0],'g');
  s = s.replace(regularExp,reg[1])
});

console.log(JSON.parse(s));
```